# Include a Class in another model / class / lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, include

I need to use function "image_path" in my lib class. I tried this (and couple of other variations):

```
class CustomHelpers::Base
  include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
  def self.image_url(source)
    abs_path = image_path(source)
    unless abs_path =~ /^http/
      abs_path = "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{abs_path}"
    end
    abs_path
  end
end
```

But it didn't work. Am I doing it right?

Another question is, how do I find the right class to include? For example if I look at this module: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html is there a rule of thumb how to include that module in a model / library / class / anything else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You include a module, so all methods on it are in InstanceMethods.

But you try call it by ClassMethods.

So try `extend ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper`, not include it

Comment: Thanks for your answer, much appreciated. However I got this error: undefined method `image_path' for ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper:Module what does it mean?

Comment: it's if you extend AssetTagHelper on your class ?

Comment: Thanks! I now know the difference between extend and include, your answer now made sense for me. Learning the fundamentals is very important, apparently

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to put all such classes under some directories and include such paths in `autoload_paths`. So if had to include **lib**,**presenters** and **jobs** directories then this is how I would autoload them in my app.

**config/application.rb**

```
 config.autoload_paths += ["#{config.root}/lib", './app/jobs', './app/presenters']
```